# formated output of JS contents into a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript file with the following content and would like to generate a dynamic html table with it's content

```
(function($) {
  My.Shortcuts = { 
    a:   'Name',
    b:    'Elvis',
    c:    'Fun'
  };

  My.Plugins.extend({
    Name: {
      url: 'http://www.name.com'
      example: 'some example text here'
    },
    Elvis: {
      url: 'http://www.elvis.com'
    },
    Fun: {
      url: 'http://anothersite.com'
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

result should be a html table or div list like:

```
a | Name | http://www.name.com (some example text here)
b | Elvis | http://www.elvis.com
c | Fun | http://anothersite.com
```

unfortunately i have no clue how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var table_html = '<table><tbody>';
for(var el in My.Shortcuts) {
    var coresp_elem = My.Plugins[My.Shortcuts[el]];
    table_html += '<tr>';
    table_html += '<td>' + el + '</td>';
    table_html += '<td>' + My.Shortcuts[el] + '</td>';
    // replace line below with for..in loop iterating over coresp_elem 
    // properties if you are dealing with multiple properties (more info below)
    table_html += '<td>' + coresp_elem.url + '</td>';
    table_html += '</tr>';
}
table_html += '</tbody></table>';

alert(table_html);
```

Should work assuming you are going to use it inside the closure with scope access to the My.Shortcuts and My.Plugins objects.

This will produce html string which you can then put somewhere on your page with:

```
$('.somewhere_on_a_page').html(table_html);
```

If you wanted to list all properties of the My.Plugins objects (like url, example, name, title, author or whatever you could have there) - you could add another for..in loop inside this one that would iterate over these properties to list all of them - you should be able to handle it from here I believe - if needed help let me know!

Tom

Comment: thank you Tom, looks like the solution! :) - but i guess i have a problem with the access of My.Shortcuts, because i just include the first part dynamically with <script src="plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and add your code under it in the main file to generate the output.

Comment: you need to add it inside the `(function($) { // plugin code })(jQuery)` closure, otherwise you won't be able to see the variables inside of it as they are hidden inside the closure's scope. So you have to do it inside of it or expose the objects you want to display to global scope so you can access them - though it will require changing code inside the closure as well

Comment: my error in reasoning, is it possible to just read the plugins.js somehow and use it?

Comment: I'm afraid this is the only way to do it. Unless you can do something like this at the bottom of `plugin.js` (inside the closure) `window.My = {}; window.My.Plugins = My.Plugins; window.My.Shortcuts = My.Shortcuts;` this will expose your objects to global scope and you will be able to access them from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = $('<table>');

for (var key in My.Shortcuts) {
  if (My.Shortcuts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var row = $('<tr>');
    var shortcut = My.Shortcuts[key];
    $('<td>').text(key).appendTo(row);
    $('<td>').text(shortcut).appendTo(row);

    if (My.Plugins.hasOwnProperty(shortcut) && typeof My.Plugins[shortcut] === 'object') {
      $('<td>').text(
        (My.Plugins[shortcut].hasOwnProperty('url') ?
                           My.Plugins[shortcut].url : '') +

        (My.Plugins[shortcut].hasOwnProperty('example') ?
               '(' + My.Plugins[shortcut].example + ')' : '')
      ).appendTo(row);
    }
    row.appendTo(table);
  }
}
```

This creates a table element dynamically which will be stored in the 'table' variable. You can then add that to the document as you wish. It will also include example text in parenthesis if any available.

Comment: Actually string concatenation is much faster method of creating larger DOM structures compared to separate elements creation - especially if you wrap every single one of them with jQuery object.